# Using LAME.DLL from C#, MSCORLIB exception?

Tags: c#, mp3, wav, lame

Yes, I have Googled this and found absolutely nothing useful.

I want to use LAME.DLL (NOT LAME.EXE) from C# to turn a WAV into an MP3.

The two CodeProject examples (MP3compressor and Aumpel) that every screen scraping help forum points to are broken.  In the EncodeChunk() function, it throws an MSCORLIB engine execution exception right where it calls down to the pointer overload of beEncodeChunk().  The error message almost immediately crashes the VS2005 debugger and I get an uncaught exception running it regularly.  Running in debug or release mode doesn't change anything, nor does allowing unsafe code.

The Aumpel CodeProject page says source code updates can be found on his site, but this is untrue as pretty much everything but the Paypal link is missing or broken and there's no telling if purchasing his program grants access to said source code or not.

Has anyone seen any working alternatives to using an ugly command line call or porting the LAME source to C#?